# Zend framerwork execute code on module preDispatch

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi there so I created a `Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract` and on `routeStartup` I do some checkings and insert data into the database, the problem is if I access a page only once, it executes like 5 times, so I will have 5 rows in the table.

Do you know how to do a controller preDispatch function that it will only execute once, I need to do some checkings everytime to user, refreshes/access a page.

Answer (score 1):

The controller plugin methods should only execute once. The only reason they wouldn't is if you application uses `_forward()` to forward the request to another action, as this results in another dispatch cycle.

I'd suggest adding a little debugging in your function temporarily to log the REQUEST_URI perhaps using `error_log()`. It might be something like your browser requesting `/favicon.ico`, which results in a 404 page which is also served by your ZF app (thus also uses the plugin).

Comment: Great answer, but this is not really a solutions, because if the CDN goes down or something and can't do a request on the frontend, basically my code won't work right. I need a more independent way

Comment: I didn't suggest a solution. I was just suggesting you do some debugging to try and work out why the plugin is running multiple times. Then you can work out what you need to change (if anything).

Comment: So I'm calling the plugin on the bootstrap, now if I don't have (Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) on the function it inserts the data only once, but if I don't pass that parameter to the function it throws an error.I also deleted all the html and still insert 3 times if I have the parameter on the function preDispatch()

Comment: When you say you are 'calling the plugin on the bootstrap' what do you mean? Could you edit your question to include that code?